# Research about best way to present multiple products on one page

Tags: optimization

I am updating a webshop page.

This is a fairly simple page that displays all the products that we currently sell. The page in development is visible here ( https://www.ortho.nl/wwebshop ).

Now I was curious, and since I can't find anything via google etc..(probaly don't know the right keywords) what the best way is to present multiple products on one page.

Should you use borders? Should you use colours? Which colours? what kind of tweaks will direct the customers attention to the right place?

Does anyone know from experience or via research(and could you point me in the right direction to find that research) what the best way to present products is so conversion/clickthrough is optimised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting study which there are a number of is ecommerce grid vs list views. One such example is http://www.getelastic.com/grid-vs-list/

> One of the testing ideas covered in the webinar Best Ecommerce Tests —
>   Case Studies & Practical Advice to Raise Conversions Before the
>   Holidays is grid view vs. list view in search results.
>
> We know from eye-tracking and search engine behavior studies that,
>   when presented with a list of search results, people often click the
>   first result – paying attention to the top 3 or so. Rarely do folks
>   click to the next page (past the 10th result).

A few other resrouces
http://www.proimpact7.com/ecommerce-blog/search-results-grid-vs-list-view/

This has Google Analytics Funnel data to show conversions
http://uxmovement.com/navigation/increasing-ecommerce-conversion-rates-category-page/

Answer (score 1):

Just to add this result from the A/B test I have conducted.

It clearly shows with a 3 percentpoint difference that 3 rows works better to get people to return to the page and to give them incentive to order.

That means with a 1000 orders, you get 30 more orders... that's a lot of difference by such a small change.

```
            Click ratio pageviews   Unique views    Rate of returning visits    Click rate on order button
3 rows      166         1224            848                 69,28%                      19,58 %
4 rows      146         1273            861                 67,64%                      16,96 %
```

Answer (score 0):

You could really benefit from doing so A/B testing, using a product like - [Optimizley](https://www.optimizely.com/) (theres others too) and also using some eye tracking analytics like [Crazy Egg](http://www.crazyegg.com/).

This way youll be able to draw you own conclusions as minor tweaks can make quite a difference, but there so personal to each site.

Comment: Thank you for the links. I'm more looking for research papers on what works(for example an orange button ups your conversion ratio by 5%)

Comment: Its just so personal no one thing is going to be correct, theres just to many variables on each site. Heres an interesting article about how they managed to up conversions for Haiti donations - http://www.irise.com/blog/2012/04/28/not-sure-user-testing-is-important-maybe-1-million-dollars-will-help-convince-you/